# How to optimize loops for large CSV files data extraction

Tags: php, file, loops, csv

I have a question about code optimization.
I haven't coded anything besides simple loops in over ten years.

I created the code below, which works fine but is super slow for my needs.

In essence, I have 2 CSV files:

- a source CSV file that has about 500 000 records, let's say: att1, att2, source_id, att3, att4 (in reality there are about 40 columns)
- a main CSV file that has about 120 million records, let's say: att1, att2, att3, main_id, att4 (in reality there are about 120 columns)

For each source_id in the source file, my code parses the main file for all the lines where main_ id == source_id and it writes each of those lines in a new file.

Do you have any suggestion on how I could optimize the code, to go much much faster?

```
<?php

$mf = "main.csv";
$mf_max_line_length = "512";
$mf_id = "main_id";

$sf = "source.csv";
$sf_max_line_length = "884167";
$sf_id = "source_id";


if (($mf_handle = fopen($mf, "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    // Read the first line of the main CSV file
    // and look for the position of main_id
    $mf_data = fgetcsv($mf_handle, $mf_max_line_length, ",");
    $mf_id_pos = array_search ($mf_id, $mf_data);

    // Create a new main CSV file
    if (($nmf_handle = fopen("new_main.csv", "x")) !== FALSE)
    {
        fputcsv($nmf_handle,$mf_data);
    } else {
        echo "Cannot create file: new_main.csv" . $sf;
        break;
    }
}

// Open the source CSV file
if (($sf_handle = fopen($sf, "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    // Read the first line of the source CSV file
    // and look for the position of source_id
    $sf_data = fgetcsv($sf_handle, $sf_max_line_length, ",");
    $sf_id_pos = array_search ($sf_id, $sf_data);

    // Go trhough the whole source CSV file
    while (($sf_data = fgetcsv($sf_handle, $sf_max_line_length, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        // Open the main CSV file
        if (($mf_handle = fopen($mf, "r")) !== FALSE)
        {
            // Go trhough the whole main CSV file
            while (($mf_data = fgetcsv($mf_handle, $mf_max_line_length, ",")) !== FALSE)
            {
                // If the source_id matches the main_id
                // then we write it into the new_main CSV file
                if ($mf_data[$mf_id_pos] == $sf_data[$sf_id_pos])
                {
                    fputcsv($nmf_handle,$mf_data);
                }
            }
            fclose($mf_handle);
        }
    }
    fclose($sf_handle);
    fclose($nmf_handle);
}

?>
```

Comment: Your problem is that you're using nested loops to look for your join. Basically, for each line that you have in your source file, you're going to iterate through the entirety of your main file. That means that instead of 120.5 Million (500,000 + 120,000,000) reads, you're ending up with 60 trillion (500,000 * 120,000,000) reads. Try caching the result of your main file into an array in one loop, keyed by the value of the index you're searching for. Then the other loop can use a simple `isset` check on that array.

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid to blow up my laptop by loading the 500 000 rows (about 1Gb of data) and 120 million rows (about 25Gb) but I can setup a VM with enough memory to handle it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for mysql.

First, you'll need to create tables based on all your fields. [See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html)

Then, you'll load your data.  [See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

Finally, you'll create a query like:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/something.csv' 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM source_table INNER JOIN main_table ON 
    source_table.source_id=main_table.main_id;
```

Comment: That is actually very smart, it will give me a lot more flexibility and ease to do manipulate the data without development.
Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You could optimize even further with indexes on your id columns and any other columns you want to run WHERE statements on. Look for the mysql docs on indexes. Its like CREATE INDEX 'somename' on sometable(somefield);